# *solved* Nginx Rewrite : Regex failed, i need some advice

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I tried many versions but my regex doesn't work.

**url tested** : https://mywebsite.com/mypage.html#page123

**All of this fail**

```
rewrite ^/\#(.*)$ /myscript.php?mode=multi&blob=$1 break 
rewrite ^/\#(page)[0-9]$ /myscript.php?mode=multi&blob=$1 break
rewrite ^/[[:graph:]](page)[0-9]$ /myscript.php?mode=multi&blob=$1 break
```

**nginx reboot fail because {1,3} part**

```
rewrite ^/\#(page)[0-9]{1,3}*$ /myscript.php?mode=multi&blob=$1 break
```

**OK, this works fine but missing information about page**

```
rewrite ^/([a-z0-9\-]+).html$ /myscript.php?mode=default&id=$1 break;
```

myscript.php has only one line :

```
print_r($\_REQUEST);  
exit();
```

Each time, my script only print : Array ( [mode] => default [id] => mypage )

*(sorry, bad english sometime)*

All of this works fine too on https://regex101.com/

Comment: fragments(#) part of the url's are only handled by the browser. fragments are not sent to the server.

Comment: oh no...
Thanks, i will change my link.